# C# Implicit Conversion Operator and is/as operator

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I'm creating a composite object that I want to be able to be used anywhere one of its wrapped objects could be used.  So given the following objects:

```
public class Foo{}

public class FooWrapper{
    private Foo _foo = new Foo();

    public static implicit operator Foo(FooWrapper wrapper)
    {
       return wrapper._foo;
    }
}
```

I want to make the following tests pass:

```
public class ConversionTests
{
     private FooWrapper _uat = new FooWrapper();

     [Test]
     public void Can_Use_Is_Operator()
     {
          Assert.IsTrue(_uat is Foo);
     }

     [Test]
     public void Can_Use_As_Operator()
     {
          Assert.IsTrue(null != _uat as Foo);
     }
}
```

I've taken a look at the MSDN documentation:
is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx
as: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The *is* documentation implies it is not possible,

> Note that the is operator only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, are not considered.

Does anyone know if there's a way to construct FooWrapper so is/as conversions will work?  Implementing an interface like IConvertible perhaps?

Bonus question: Anyone know why as/is doesn't consider user-defined conversions?

(And sorry if this question is a dup.  'as' and 'is' appear to be stop words here on stackoverflow (as with most search engines), making it quite difficult to search for questions that contain these keywords.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The is documentation implies it is not possible

The documentation is correct.

> Does anyone know if there's a way to construct FooWrapper so is/as conversions will work?

I know. There is not. (Aside from, obviously, making `FooWrapper` a derived class of `Foo`.)

The `is` and `as` operators are there to tell you what an object **really is**. Don't try to make them lie.

> Implementing an interface like IConvertible perhaps?

Nope.

> Anyone know why as/is doesn't consider user-defined conversions?

First, because like I just said, the purpose of `is` is to tell you what the object *really is*.

Second, because suppose for the sake of argument the C# compiler team wished to add a new operator, say `frob`, that has the semantics of an `as` operator that uses user-defined conversions.  `x frob Foo` gives you back a `Foo` when `x` is a `FooWrapper`.  Describe please the IL you would like to see generated for that expression. I think by engaging in this exercise you'll see why it is a hard problem.

Comment: After reading through your response (and @alexei-levenkov and @jim-mischel),I think I may have a misunderstanding of the intention of the `is` `as` operators. I very seldom need to know what an object **really is**, I only care how I can use it.  So if I have a `List<IBar>` and `Foo`, as well as several other classes implement `IBar`, when I enumerate through the list, I don't care what the actual object is, I only care what I can do with it: `foreach(var item in new List<IBar()>{ var foo = item as Foo;  if (null != foo){ /*callSomeMethodThatWantsFoo(foo)*/}` Is this not the proper usecase?

Comment: @ppittle: OK, so let's suppose that `Bar` implements `IBar`, the list contains a `Bar`, and there is a user-defined conversion from `Bar` to `Foo`. You haven't answered my question, which is:  what IL would you like generated for the `as` operator that allows a `Foo` to come out the other end?

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge of IL is a bit limited, so I would expect the equivalent of this C#: `public static T frob<T>(object o){ try{ return (T)o;} catch(InvalidCastException){return default(T);}}.  Although, now that I think of it, this is what I always assumed the `is` operator did (albeit in a much more elegant form, ie without the try catch) is to check if an explicit cast would succeed and if so perform the cast, and if not return null.  So I guess now the question is what's the difference between the IL `isinst` and `initobj T`?

Comment: @ppittle ok, try your proposed code. Does it do what you think it does?

Comment: No, no the code does not.  My FooWrapper's implicit conversion method is not called when a FooWrapper is passed into `frob` as an _object_.  Could I trouble you for why this is?  Is it the same reason this wont compile: `public T Frob<T,K>(K obj){ return (T)obj; }`?

Comment: And if I have complete control over FooWrapper, but no control over Foo, is there a better way to write Frob than this (ie, tag FooWrapper with a custom interface): `FooWraper : IFrobConvertable{ public T Frob<T>(){ return t == typeof(Foo) ? (T))(this._foo as object) : default(T);}}`                                                        `public T frob<T>(object o){ var frober = o as IFrobConvertable;     if (null != frober){ return frober.FrobConvert<T>() ?? o as T;} return o as T; }`

Comment: @ppittle: Your conjecture is correct. Both fail to compile because **there is insufficient information at compile time to generate code that is both performant and correct**. The fundamental problem is that a cast means *two* things: it can mean "I know this object **really is** of this other type; if I'm wrong you're allowed to throw an exception". And it can mean "I know this object **really is not** of this other type; compiler, please find a mechanism that takes an object of this type and produces an 'associated' object of the target type". These are opposites!

Comment: @ppittle: The compiler has no problem generating efficient code for the first kind of cast -- a *representation preserving* conversion. That kind of conversion is simply a dynamic check of the type tag on the object with an exception thrown if the check fails. But the compiler has no way to generate efficient code for the second kind of cast -- a *representation changing* conversion -- unless the source and target types are *known* to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In order for `FooWrapper` to be considered a `Foo`, `FooWrapper` would have to inherit from `Foo`. That is:

```
class FooWrapper: Foo
{
}
```

The problem, though, is that if you wanted your wrapper to also wrap `Bar` objects, you can't. Because C# does not support multiple inheritance.

Typically if you need a wrapper that will act like multiple objects, you have it implement interfaces. So, for example, you would have:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Foo: IFoo  // implements the IFoo interface
{
}

public interface IBar
{
}

public class Bar: IBar
{
}

public class MyWrapper: IFoo, IBar  // Implements the IFoo and IBar interfaces
{
    private IFoo _theFoo;
    private IBar _theBar;
    public MyWrapper(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
    {
        _theFoo = foo;
        _theBar = bar;
    }
}
```

And of course `MyWrapper` would have to implement all the methods of `IFoo` and `IBar`, passing the calls on to the proper contained object. So if `IFoo` declared a `Frob` method, you would have (in the `MyWrapper` class):

```
    public void Frob()
    {
        _theFoo.Frob();
    }
```

That's implicit interface implementation. You might also have to look into explicit implementation of interface methods.

To create a wrapper:

```
MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(new Foo(), new Bar());
```

Your tests, then, would use `is` and `as` to check for interfaces rather than concrete classes.

```
var isFoo = wrapper is IFoo;
IFoo myFoo = wrapper as IFoo;
```

Comment: "The problem, though, is that if you wanted your wrapper to also wrap Bar objects" - hit the nail on the head with that one.  I'm experimenting with composting multiple objects (`Foo`, `Bar`, etc), so direct inheritance is out.  And I am checking against Framework objects, so I can't modify the wrapped objects by adding additional interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The only option for `is`/`as` to work with the wrapper class is if wrapping class is indeed wrapped class. If class you want to wrap is not sealed you can derive from it...

Now what you are trying to actually achieve is not possible in general case - .Net/C# statically detects what methods will be called and all non-virtual methods of your wrapped object must be called directly on object of that type (or derived one), but you'll not be able to override them in any way. Static methods are even harder.

```
var item = new InnerType();
// you can't create any class that will replace method in this call
item.NonVirtual();

// No way to replace static method with wrapper
var result = InnerType.StaticMethod();

// At least virtual methods can be overriden if Wrapper derives from InnerType
item.VirtualMethod();
```

If your code uses interfaces to interact with objects your task is much easier as substituting an interface with alternative implementation is completely supported. Either manual wrapper or automatically created via reflection/Emit would work.

```
var itemByInterface = (IInnerType)Factory.CreateInnerType();
itemByInterface.InterfaceMethod();

// is/as checks should use interface
var isRightType = itemByInterface is IInnerType;

// do not use static/non-interface calls
```

My thoughts on why is/as do not consider other conversion:

- expectation of the operation is to be very quick and light weight check - other conversions may need to create objects/unpredictable in how long it would take,
- it significantly increases number of options that can be considered by compiler so slowing it down
- in many other cases where object are used conversions will not be considered, so may lead to inconsistent code behavior where `is` reports success but object fails to be used correctly (like instance added to list).