# Why does the "as" operator not use an implicit conversion operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting, type-conversion

I have defined implicit string conversion from/to a certain type in C# (dummy code):

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyType(string fromString)
    {
        return new MyType { Value = fromString };
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyType myType)
    {
        return myType.Value;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in external library code, an instance of `MyType` is passed to a method, as an `object` parameter. Part of that method looks like something along these lines:

```
private void Foo(object value)
{
    // ... code omitted
    var bar = value as string // note that value is an instance of MyType at runtime
    if(bar != null) // false, cast fails
    {
       // ... code omitted
    }
}
```

Why does the cast not use the implicit converter? I thought the whole point of these was to make casting and transparent usage possible?

Would this work if `MyType` had an `explicit` converter instead? If so, (how) can I have both?

By the way, the cast definitely works if the type is known at **compile-time**. Is this because operators are `static`? Is there something like non-static conversion operators?

P.S. I'm actually most interested in the differences between compile-time behaviour and runtime behaviour, so I've a follow-up question: [Why are implicit type conversion operators not dynamically usable at runtime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35509502/1313143)

Comment: As an aside, I've never heard the `as` operator referred to as a "soft cast" before.

Comment: @JonSkeet that genuinely surprises me, maybe not an official term but I've definitely seen it lots of times.

Comment: A search for "soft cast" and C# gets me 636 results, which is a *tiny* number in my view. I would definitely avoid it in the future - it's certainly *not* part of the C# specification terminology.

Comment: @JonSkeet is there a similarly succinct (but more correct) equivalent term?

Comment: @RichardEverett: It's "the `as` operator". That's all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll keep that in the back of my head should I ever need it in more official or public communication. My teammates understand me when I use it however, which is most important I think.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: But in that case you're just reinforcing the use of non-standard terminology within your team. If you use the standard terminology I suspect they'll *also* understand you - but none of you will have to change how you talk when discussing things externally.

Comment: Why are you using "as"?  You defined implicit operators, so why not just do: 
string bar = value;
Or you could define your method as: public void Foo(string value).  If you want it to be more transparent, then just use an explicit conversion.

Comment: @returnsvoid that is library code, as mentioned in the question, I have no control over it.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  My mistake.

Comment: I've edited the title again, as you'd changed it to "explicit cast". Your code doesn't use an explicit cast - it uses the `as` operator. If you'd used `string  bar = (string) value`; that would have failed for a *different* reason.

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually wanted to know why it would not work either way. The original wording of my question was off, since I also tested it with an explicit cast but the difference was that the type was known at compile-time (silly oversight, I know). I blamed the `as` operator, while I should have been blaming the runtime behaviour.

Comment: @MDeSchaepneester: well it's still a good idea for the title to match the body of the question :) I suggest you edit the text in the body to match the code too. If you wanted to ask about an actual cast, it would have been worth doing that to start with. As it is, if you want to cover casts as well, I suggest you do that in a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, hence a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35509502/1313143

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Implicit Conversion Operator and is/as operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390664/c-sharp-implicit-conversion-operator-and-is-as-operator)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why does the soft cast not use the implicit converter?

Well, that's the way the language is specified, basically. From the C# 5 specification section 7.10.11:

> If the compile-time type of E is not dynamic, the operation E as T produces the same result as
>
> ```
> E is T ? (T)(E) : (T)null
> ```
>
> except that E is only evaluated once.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that some conversions, such as user defined conversions, are not possible with the as operator and should instead be performed using cast expressions.

Comment: That's clear enough, but would you know of any workarounds? What if I really wanted to have a type that behaves almost completely like a string (or an int, or anything else for that matter)?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: I would just give up on that as an aim, to be honest. There are always going to be problems when trying to make one type look transparently like another. I would backtrack and look at other designs instead.

Comment: Fair enough, but had it not been for this one limitation everything would have worked out nicely though. Thanks anyway, if you don't know a workaround then I'm certain no one else does :)

Answer (score 10):

`as` keyword doesn't considers the user defined operators. You need to use a cast operator instead. Related [article from Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/08/whats-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators/)

In your case both explicit and implicit operators can't help you as you're trying to cast from `object` to `string` not from `MyType` to `string`. For user defined conversion operators to work, compile time type of the instance to be of type `MyType` instead of `object`. Because there is no conversion exist from `object` to `string` but from `MyType` to `string`.

Comment: Using `dynamic` would make the cast work, I believe. (Would have to check though.) That wouldn't help with `as` though.

Comment: In other words, the cast would only work if the parameter is actually an instance of `string` at that moment?

Comment: Exactly. added supporting article.

Answer (score 9):

The C# language Specification explicitly mentions this in the documentation for `as`:

> Note that some conversions, such as user defined conversions, are not
>   possible with the as operator and should instead be performed using
>   cast expressions.

So you have to cast it.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that an implicit conversion operator would have to get called. In this case, any call

> var castObj = rawObj as SomeType;

would require the .NET runtime to use reflection in order to determine whether the "rawObj" object has a conversion operator. Obviously, this would be much more computationally expensive than just to check if the object is of type SomeType or its subtype. Better to have a fast and predictable operator than a more versatile, but much slower one.